# Understanding Meanwell CV+CC driver characteristics

Tags: led-driver, constant-current

I have an LED fixture that can take 2 to 2.5 amps. Vf is around 36 volts.

I am planning to use Meanwell ELG series driver to power it up. [[Datasheet here]](https://www.meanwell.com/Upload/PDF/ELG-100/ELG-100-SPEC.PDF)

This particular model can work in CV+CC mode and I want to make sure if I understand it correctly. It gives the following graph:

[image: graph]

I want to use ELG-100-42 model.

[image: specs]

If I use ELG-100-42 model LED driver, my fixture will draw 2.28 amps and LED driver will be go in CC mode at that current and the output voltage will stabilize near 36 V. Since 36 V is greater than 50% of output voltage (50% x 42 V = 21 V), my output voltage and current will remain stable and it won't go into hiccup mode. Am I right?

I want to confirm if my chosen driver is suitable for my fixture or not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have used the ELG 240 in the past, so I guess the same applies to the ELG-100.

If Vout is larger than 50% of max, so you will see a constant output, but there will be the usual ripple at the switching frequency ~100 kHz.

Even below 50% Vout, I was able to get a rather stable output. Down to well below 10 % Vout. However, the ripple frequency drops significantly. The output didnt go into DCM until very low Vout.

Comment: I wanted to specifically understand whether the driver will go into CC mode with my fixture supplying 2.28 amps or not.

Comment: The contral signal that you put into the module sets a desired current level. When you put in full scale control signal (e.g. 10V) then you ask for 2.28 A regardless of the necessary voltage. The module is basically *always* in CC mode, unless it is voltage limited.